# Error in node, npm versions, installations. SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

I have been receiving this error when I try to run `npm run server` or `npm install` or `npm -v`.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
  let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
  ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
```

I have this inside scripts tag in the package.json `"server": "nodemon server/bin/www"`.

`nodejs -v` outputs `v10.1.0`

`node -v` outputs `v5.10.1`.

Few people have suggested that it is a problem with npm or node versions or npm getting installed in multiple places. I have tried uninstalling, installing back again, upgrading. But nothing seems to work.

I have my directory structure like this:

[image]

Any suggestions, please! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

- Have you ever tried to install the Microsoft Azure command line tools,using:

```
sudo apt - get install nodejs - legacy
sudo apt - get install npm
sudo npm install - g azure - cli
```

or

```
nvm install node
```

- This could be also because you are not in the desired directory. 
  You need to first get into the desired directory. Mine was my_direc 
  directory. So I typed in `cd my_direc` and then `npm install`.
- **OR** 
  First download json package file from https://github.com/npm/read-package-json and then run npm install from terminal.

does it run?
***Good Luck***

Comment: I have my directory structure like this, all in the root folder: /client, /public, /scripts, /server, /server/app.js, /src, package.json, package-lock.json. I went to this root directory, then executed `npm install`. Although, wherever I type npm, the above mentioned error occurrs. Also, I already have node, nodejs, npm installed. Please see the question as I have mentioned the versions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, no, I have never used azure command line tools. How does it help though? What do you think is the root of my problem, wrong versions of node or npm trying to run together?

Comment: I would suggest to see if your version of the node is actually usable... but I'm not really sure where your problem could be...